# Determining which derailleur hanger is compatible with a frame

Tags: frames, derailleur

When your derailleur hanger needs replacing, is there a good resource for matching frames to hangers?

Mine was recently bent, so I had to dig through some websites and compare pictures of the hangers to my bent unit. Surely there's a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: Would love to know if there is a free resource. Large high volume bike shops have access to a pretty complete reference site (I've got a link at home, I'll try to remember to paste it in later)...but it's too pricey for individuals ($50/month if memory serves). Best bet is to call your manufacturer and see what the "official" hanger to use is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wheels Manufacturing has a feature to search by brand for their hangers. Just one company of many that produces replacement hangers.

http://wheelsmfg.com/products/derailleur-hangers.html

Comment: The other answer is actually much better...

Answer (score 5):

http://derailleurhanger.com/ allows you to search by brand or design (number of holes). It being a distributor of Wheels Mfg parts, the prices may be slightly lower than purchasing from Wheels Mfg directly, especially for single-digit quantities. The search function does require JavaScript to be enabled, however.

Comment: According to their [policies](http://derailleurhanger.com/policies.php): "We are very proud to offer high quality, USA produced derailleur hangers from Wheels Manufacturing, which is based in Colorado. Wheels Mfg hangers are CNC machined from aircraft-grade 6061-series aluminum, and anodized black. We also offer hangers from several other high quality manufacturers. When sourcing hangers, our goal is to stock hangers that are CNC machined from aircraft-grade aluminum."

Answer (score 0):

There is not one place that has an exact list of every bike model ever produced but if you go onto one of the sites mentioned or http://mechhanger.com/ just type inn your bike make and it will narrow it down to a few derailleur hangers to compare. If you are still stuck, send them a picture and let them do the hard work!