# Replacement dropouts with derailleur hanger for Kona Unit

Tags: dropouts

A friend of mine has a single speed Kona Unit and wants to make it geared. The model he has (likely 2012 or 2013 model) uses sliding dropout. He currently has single speed dropout plates without a derailleur hanger. What replacement plates are available for the sliding dropouts with a derailleur hanger?  Are these paragon dropouts (or compatible with paragon), Tange dropouts, or custom to Kona?

Any suggestions on which dropout plates to use to replace the drive side with a geared dropout plate would be helpful.

FYI: I referenced all sites listed in the following question and didn't find sliding dropouts for this bike on any of them:
[Determining which derailleur hanger is compatible with a frame](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/10286/determining-which-derailleur-hanger-is-compatible-with-a-frame)

Current dropout looks like:
[image]
<sub>(source: [bikeman.com](https://www.bikeman.com/store/graphics/00000001/Alt-KON/KON-F12UN16-02.jpg))</sub>

Comment: One thing to note, the channel the derailleur hanger plates are mounted on is not continuous. The dropout connects in the center, creating two separate channels for the slider bolts instead of one large channel for both bolts.

Comment: You should call Kona - they (used?) to sell a kit for adding a derailleur to the Unit. Though the normal solution for the Unit for gearing is to use an IGH.

Comment: Maybe fabricate.  Looks like you can use the existing for the other side.

Comment: Yeah, just need the drive side with hanger built in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

## [KONA #CMPHCC Derailleur Hanger](http://www.probikeshop.com/kona-cmphcc-derailleur-hanger/84435.html)

[image]

Comment: This does look like what I've been searching for.

Comment: If anyone has a US supplier they can link me to, that would be awesome.  The shipping costs as much as the dropout from the UK.

Comment: Beggers can't be choosers, there's on on [ebay for $71USD](http://www.ebay.com/itm/D276-derailleur-hanger-gear-dropout-for-KONA-/111137914933?pt=Cycling_Parts_Accessories&hash=item19e0560035), other than that here are some more buying options: [1](http://picclick.com/D276-derailleur-hanger-gear-dropout-for-KONA-111001726766.html), [2](http://soshanger.com/D276-derailleur-hanger-KON), [3](http://www.hibike.com/shop/product/p1f95cbd7034bc8174856e1ad78d59ea1/KONA-derailleur-hanger.html#var_13389391), [4](http://www.jejamescycles.co.uk/kona-derailleur-hanger-model-cc-id86028.html).

Answer (score -1):

I think you could get it directly from Kona. 
[Kona dropout](http://konaparts.com/product/hangers-dropouts-dropout-cc/)