# Specialized Rockhopper derailleur hanger needed.....which one?

Tags: mountain-bike, repair, identify-this-bike, dropouts

[image]

I need to know which drop out hanger I need for this Specialized Rockhopper. 
Part of the frame is chipped at the dropout but it will still bolt on. I just don't know which hanger I need.

[image]
[image]

Comment: A picture of the hanger area could help.

Comment: The answers on this question should enable you to find what you're looking for 
 https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/10286/determining-which-derailleur-hanger-is-compatible-with-a-frame

Comment: If you can give us more details wheel size, number of speeds, approx. age. There are data bases that can help but you need at least a few details. If you are trying to save a few bucks by circumventing your local bike shop in this case it won't help much. There are few suppliers and on line prices are close to what the bike shop charges, generally around $30 US.

Comment: Personal opinion - I would not be confident that the rear wheel would be properly held in to the damaged dropout. *Maybe* I'd ride this on good road surfaces, I would not ride it on rough trails.

Comment: OJS_ There is a close up of the drive side hangar area.

Comment: Mikes - its a 26 inch wheel, I fix bikes all the time and I know for a fact that for me to take a bike to bike shop would be  a last resort, but in this case you may be right. I dont know the age or exact model of this rockhopper, so a shop might help. I simply need the hanger code. I have identified the code for my other two bikes, and saved money not taking them to bikeshops for the same. Sorry, but $30 for a drop out hanger is silly. My other bikes have reliable and correct hangers for about 10, bought online. I even carry a spare over distance

Comment: Argenti...I have already ridden this with an axle mounted hanger, held on tight with the QR skewer. It worked. I even indexed it, but obviously, it was a temporary measure, and the rear mech needs proper anchorage. So the drop out IS safe to ride, the snapped part is below, does not bear any weight, and maysimply be supportive of the hanger area. So without it just means a more delicate hanger, but they are meant to be anyway...like a lizards tail kinda thing.

Comment: Do you have the lower part still?  Should be bolted to your derailleur and not dropped.  Lay them out together for a better idea of the shape you're looking for.

Comment: Can you tell me where you located the hanger and bolts?

Answer (score 2):

I googled "specialized rockhopper derailleur hanger" and one of the links was

https://media.specialized.com/support/0000004464/0000004464_CG0421_hanger_fit_chart_rev2013.pdf

The Rockhopper table is on page 4 of 9 and looks like this

```
ROCKHOPPER
2011 2011 Rockhopper M4SL 26"/29er 9895-4021
2010 2010 Rockhopper SL            9895-4021
2011 2013 Rockhopper M4 26"        9895-4021
2006 2010 Rockhopper HT            9895-4021
2011 2011 Rockhopper Comp 29” HT LEFT  9898-4240    RIGHT 9898-4245
2010 2010 Rockhopper SL 29”        9895-4021
2008 2010 Rockhopper 29” HT LEFT   9898-4240
2008 2010 Rockhopper 29” HT RIGHT  9898-4245
2011 2013 Myka HT 29”              9895-4021
2008 2013 Myka HT 26"              9895-4021
2005 (Late) Rockhopper HT          9895-4021
2004 2005 Rockhopper HT            9894-4206
2003 2003 Rockhopper HT            989-4271
1996 2002 Rockhopper HT            989-4261
2003 2003 Rockhopper FSRxc         989-4271
```

So, with some exceptions, half of them use **9895-4021** which looks like this:

[image: http://www.mcconveycycles.com/images/specialized_gear_hanger_g_9895-4021.jpg]

And is mostly in black with the odd silver one around.

The earlier models all use different hangers, so you'll need to remember when you got it, and work out its age from there.

Interestingly, wheel size seems to be unrelated.

---

EDIT OP says its a "specialized hanger 12" which seems to look like this:

[image: https://www.marleen.co.nz/slir/w-h-q90/4121/]

Comment: That definitely looks promising, with the latest photo included in the question. OP has something to compare the broken hanger with, to make their decision. I'm wondering if they're the original owner though, having misspelt [Spunge] in the duplicate question ;)

Comment: wrong hanger there.... nearly though....its a specialised hanger 12 thats needed and i now have one.....but i now need fixing bolts...

Comment: @puzylo Great work - when you have it all working and together, come back and add your own answer, list all the part numbers etc you have, and any problems resolved.  You're totally encouraged to do this, and mark your own answer as "accepted" because its what worked for you.

Comment: And potentially a second fixing bolt hole which hasn’t snapped off the frame dropou...

Answer (score 1):

If you take a pic of your bike's hanger then go take a look at this site: https://derailleurhanger.com/

Comment: Ive sorted this in as far as the answer to this question is that the hager needed is indeed a SPECIALISED HANGER 12. .....however I now need the bolts and they didnt come with the hanger and I cant find anywhere selling them....any advice? size of fixing bolts would be handy right now....nearly there :)

Comment: What’s that blue thing in the last photo, a little bolt head? It’s snapped off but might help with sizing. Unfortunately you’re going to need two, the photo looks like one has snapped off with the frame damage which would be really bad luck, but not necessarily game over