# Identify bike brand to fit gear hanger!

Tags: frames, hanger, bso

I have bought a new used bike, I got it very cheap since it was pretty broken up. I have replaced most of the parts and repainted the bike so it looks fine. The only thing I have a problem with is the gear hanger. When I got the bike it was broken of and I have a really hard time finding the right one. The bike frame is made of aluminum.

On the bike frame before I repainted it said "Peak Pt Arlington". But I can't really find any bike with that brand. The closest thing I got was [this](https://balstaauktionshall.nu/objekt/cykel-herr-peak-pt-arlington-28-24vxl-ct535cm/5965).

[image: bike]

But there isn't any info about it.

Here is a picture of the broken hanger:

[image: broken hanger]

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Here are some more pictures:

https://image.ibb.co/fTCvXU/IMG_20180925_151050.jpg

https://image.ibb.co/jTA4Rp/IMG_20180925_151228.jpg

https://image.ibb.co/dCY2CU/IMG_20180925_151243.jpg

Comment: Do you have a picture of the other half of the hanger and the dropout?

Comment: Try https://wheelsmfg.com/ .  They have a  "guaranteed to fit" policy.

Comment: The answers on this question should enable you to find what you're looking for: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/10286/determining-which-derailleur-hanger-is-compatible-with-a-frame

Comment: @DavidRicherby - "standard". Wheelsmfg has about 280 different designs on their poster; knowing the make and model and year of a bike can narrow things down super quickly, particularly for larger brands (e.g. Trek, Giant, Specialized). Of course, a large number of those designs clearly won't fit this frame when you look at the shapes, but theres a decent number of similar looking ones which won't necessarily fit off hand.

Comment: @Batman - But, IIRC, you can send wheelsmfg photos of the bike and other info and they will advise you.

Comment: BTW, it's generally a good idea to take some pictures of a bike frame before you repaint it, as questions like this come up quite often.

Comment: @KeithWM Unfortunately i only have the one part of the hanger that shows in the picture.
DanielRHicks Yes well, At least i learn from my mistakes!

Answer (score 1):

Many bike shops have charts (posters) which they can use to match derailleur hanger to suitable replacements which they can order from a place like wheelsmfg.com.

I'd suggest taking the piece(s) you have to a bikeshop with such a chart and trying to use the chart to find a suitably matching hanger. This is likely easier than trying to search the varieties of hangers online on your own (since there are a lot that look the same, and if it doesn't come up in their search by manufacturer, you're going to have issues).

There are also various options for adding hangers to frames which don't have hangers if you really must; For example, the Problem Solvers Universal Derailleur Hanger replaces one side of your quick release. But a fitting hanger is probably better.

Looks like the brand is from Sweden, possibly, based on google image search. So you may want to look at something like wheelsmfg for Europe.

Comment: I will take some pictures of the frame also and edit the question and upload here, i will also contact wheelsmfg and see what they say. And since i live in Sweden it makes sense that the brand is Swedish hehe. Thanks for your answer!